# Can no longer login after update - Failed to start Service for snap application quassel-kalikiana.core

Tags: linux, packages, manjaro

After updating my Manjaro GNOME edition last night I come to login this morning and I'm presented with an error screen before the select user option even shows and gives me a logout button.

When clicking the logout button it drops down to a terminal window and says

> Failed to start Service for snap application quassel-kalikiana.core

I can't enter any commands and completely locked out of my OS and it seems like no way back in. No other errors or information is displayed so I'm really struggling on how to even start debugging this issue.

What can I do to access my desktop?

Answer (score 1):

You can try fixing the update (assuming the update caused this)

1. Boot the Manjaro Live CD.
2. Open terminal
3. `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt`
4. `sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev`
5. `sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc`
6. `sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys`
7. `sudo chroot /mnt`
8. `apt update`
9. `apt upgrade`

Also, you should check out this guide:

https://forum.manjaro.org/t/how-to-save-your-manjaro-installation-when-it-breaks/75